# RLLib - Tensorflow - InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of N which is outside the valid range of [0, N)

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray, rllib

I'm using RLLib's PPOTrainer with a custom environment, I execute `trainer.train()` two times, the first one completes successfully, but when I execute it for the second time it crashed with an error:

> lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1384, in _do_call (pid=15248)     raise type(e)(node_def, op,
>   message) (pid=15248)
>
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>
> Received a label value of 5 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5). >Label values: 5 5
>
> (pid=15248)      [[node
>   default_policy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
>   (defined at /tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]]

Here's my code:

*main.py*

```
ModelCatalog.register_custom_preprocessor("tree_obs_prep", TreeObsPreprocessor)
ray.init()

trainer = PPOTrainer(env=MyEnv, config={
    "train_batch_size": 4000,
    "model": {
        "custom_preprocessor": "tree_obs_prep"
    }
})

for i in range(2):
    print(trainer.train())
```

*MyEnv.py*

```
class MyEnv(rllib.env.MultiAgentEnv):
    def __init__(self, env_config):
        self.n_agents = 2

        self.env = *CREATES ENV*
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(5)
        self.observation_space = np.zeros((1, 12))

    def reset(self):
        self.agents_done = []
        obs = self.env.reset()
        return obs[0]

    def step(self, action_dict):
        obs, rewards, dones, infos = self.env.step(action_dict)

        d = dict()
        r = dict()
        o = dict()
        i = dict()
        for i_agent in range(len(self.env.agents)):
            if i_agent not in self.agents_done:
                o[i_agent] = obs[i_agent]
                r[i_agent] = rewards[i_agent]
                d[i_agent] = dones[i_agent]
                i[i_agent] = infos[i)agent]
        d['__all__'] = dones['__all__']

        for agent, done in dones.items():
            if done and agent != '__all__':
                self.agents_done.append(agent)

        return  o, r, d, i
```

I have no idea about what's the problem, any suggestion?
What does this error mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/6136#issuecomment-552766521) comment really helped me:

> FWIW, I think such issues can happen if NaNs appear in the policy
>   output. When that happens, you can get out of range errors.
>
> Usually it's due to the observation or reward somehow becoming NaN,
>   though it could be the policy diverging as well.

In my case, I had to modify my observations because the agent wasn't able to learn a policy and at some point in the training (at a random timestep) the returned action was `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks! I had a division by 0 error somewhere that apparently lead to that error.